# Changing focus between Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have created two activities (`ActivityA` and `ActivityB`), and I want to switch between them, i.e.:

- when a user clicks on a button in `ActivityA`, I go to `ActivityB`
- in `ActivityB`, a user inserts a message and then by pressing a button he goes to `ActivityA`

However, I am not able to retrieve the message that is arriving from `ActivityB`.

I describe my code in the following.

**Requiring `ActivityB` to start (from `ActivityA` to `ActivityB`)**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Requiring `ActivityA` to start (from `ActivityB` to `ActivityA`)**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
String message = "some text";
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);
```

**The problem**

Where should I put the code that handles the intent in `ActivityA`, as follows?

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(ActivityB.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

I am not able to retrieve it in the `onResume()` and `onRestart()` methods, thus I am obviously missing something in the handling of the activity lifecycle.

Moreover, each time I call back the `ActivityA`, it calls back the `onCreate()` method, meaning that the activity is destroyed each time, which is not what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you checked at onNewIntent

Comment: I was wondering how to maintain the activity `ActivityA` alive.

Comment: Read more here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html and article http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/

Comment: Here is more detailed article http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Call ActivityB from ActivityA using the below code.**

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,0); // '0' is requestcode
```

**When user enters the message return from the ActivityB using below code.**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("messagekey",your_message);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    setResult(1,intent); // here '1' is resultcode
    finish();
```

**and Override OnActivityResult method in ActivityA as follows**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == 1)
{
if (data != null) {
if (data.getStringExtra("messagekey") != null) {
String message_from_activityB = data.getStringExtra("messagekey");
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use startActivityForResult not the simple one StartActivity

something like this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
  startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

In ActivityB just do like this dont call ActivityA using StartIntent

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String message = "some text";
 intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", message);
 setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
 finish();

 in ActivityA override the

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(data.getExtras().containsKey("EXTRA_MESSAGE"))
      {
        // now you can access those data of ActivtyB
      }
```